# elasticsearch cluster status: Where are status changes logged?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch 1.7.2 on CentOS

**Issue**: Cluster went from green status to off green (not sure), and then back to green by itself.

- Where are cluster status changes logged?
- Where do we look to find out why/what caused the cluster status change?

We are looking in the /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log file. We only see errors related to java memory. We do not see any messages relating to cluster status changes.

**Update**

From what we can tell, even though each node will return a cluster status (green/yellow/red), at least in default settings, these statuses are not logged (as a result, it can be very hard to know when the status changed). The logs do show errors, but particularly when a problem condition clears, the logs are (in our experience so far) not helpful.

Comment: I suggest trying out Marvel or any other monitoring plugin for Elasticsearch. The series of questions related to monitoring you had in the past days are easily covered by Marvel. You are trying to reinvent the wheel here. Tools are already there.

Comment: Is marvel foss or commercial?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Thank you for all the great help here on SO. My questions come from a normal operational experience. I am not interested in a full blown monitoring approach. I need to find and understand the few core aspects of baseline health.